# How to give Free Bonus in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am runing a bitcoin investment website. I want to give user free bonus of 0.005 points on registration. I have tried following in my registration Controller to fill database table. It works perfectly but after 100 user it creat some type of bug and I get error in user login it says:
But I remove all rows of depostit table all functions work perfectly.

> trying to get property of non object

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],

    'under_reference' => $data['reference'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'verifyToken' => Str::random(40),
    'reference' => Str::random(12),
    'status' => $status,
    'image' => $image25
]);
$deposit = Deposit::create([
    'deposit_number' => date('ymd').Str::random(6).rand(11,99),
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    'plan_id' => "7",
    'percent' => "1",
    'time' => "30",
    'compound_id' => "2",
    'amount' => "0.005",
    'status' => "0"
]);
```

Comment: Sometimes `User::create` doens't return the created user. Try to look if the user is correctly return

Comment: yes registration is sucess full and new user can login also but after 2-3 days this bug become

Comment: What is the max length of the user's id?